# Backup in Linux

Tags: backup, system, storage, syslinux

The data on the hard drive is 10GB in size. Know that every day the data in the hard drive will increase by an average of 5%. So to perform level 0 (full) backup on day 0, level 1 backup on day 5 and level 2 backup on day 6, how much storage space will be needed, respectively?
I think:
Full backup = 10GB
Level 1 backup = 10 * 25% = 2.5GB
Level 2 backup = ???
Thank you!

Comment: Hello. How does this have anything to do with Ubuntu? This is a Ubuntu support site. You have a Ubuntu related question and someone here may have the answer.

Comment: Do want a backup utility or a program that will back up your drive?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: This kind of strategy might be not the best for your needs, you can consider a strategy of a yearly only full backup,  a daily incremental one & only a weekly differential one ; monthly a syncro-one on a second copy of the yearly one.   whatever the technical solution you choose, I find this really more safe, that getting a backup 0 and a daily one  (if you need security) if not it's ok on your planning

Comment: This is the kind of question that spreadsheets "excel" at answering ... 

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly:

The data on the drive increases by 5% each day.

On day 1, the size of the data is 10 GB:

```
10*0.05 = 0.5 GB increase
```

However, the size of the data is 10.5 GB on day 2:

```
10.5*0.05 = 0.525 GB increase
```

For a 5% increase each day, you would use the formula for compound interest to calculate the size of the data on the drive.

[image]

```
For 5 days at 5% (level one):
__________________ 
| P = 10 GB      |
|                |
| r = 5% = 0.05  |
|                |
| n = 1 day      |
|                |
| t = 5 days     |
|________________|

since n = 1, n cancels out so the formula is:    

A = P( 1 + r )ᵗ

A = 10( 1 + 0.05 )⁵

A = 10( 1.05 )⁵

A = 10( 1.27628156 )

A ≈ 12.76 GB
```

**It would be approximately 2.76 GB extra at level 1, not 2.5 GB.**

According to your question, a level 2 backup would be 6 days instead of 5 so use the formula and change the values accordingly.

<sub>Note: since n = 1 day, this value cancels out so it is not used in the final calculation as 1 times a number is the number and 1 divided a number is also the same number.</sub>

---

In the terminal, you can use the `bc` command to calculate the size of the data on the drive after 5 days (level 1):

```
echo "10*1.05^5" | bc -l
```

You could also create a script to calculate the value at n number of days:

```
#!/bin/bash

# script to calculate the size of 10 GB of data that increases in size by 5% each day

echo "10*1.05^$@" | bc -l
```

For example, if the name of the script is "scriptname" you would use the following to calculate the size of the data on the drive after 6 days:

```
./scriptname 6
```